# collect attributes and values into string list

Tags: list, groovy, xmlslurper, collect

I have xml data looking like this:

```
<persons>
  <person key="M">John Doe</person>
  <person key="N">Jane Doe</person>
</persons>
```

I want to collect them into a list of maps like

```
[[key: M, name: John Doe], [key: N, name: Jane Doe]]
```

and I use, after slurping the data into the variable 'p', using XmlSlurper:

```
p.collect { [key: it.@key.text(), name it.text()] }
```

but I get

```
[[key: MN, name: John DoeJane Doe]]
```

Obviously I do something very wrong, but I can't figure out what. I have tried a number of methods but get the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking for `children()` from root node.

```
def xml = """
<persons>
  <person key="M">John Doe</person>
  <person key="N">Jane Doe</person>
</persons>
"""

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

assert [
    [key:'M', name:'John Doe'], 
    [key:'N', name:'Jane Doe']
] == slurper.children().collect { 
    [ key: it.@key.text(), name: it.text() ] 
}
```

Comment: This solved it AND a couple of follow up questions. Stackoveflow turns out to be more informative than all the documentation I've read.